# Can't find qt creator after building qt statically

Tags: c++, qt

I used this

http://tmacdev.com/2013/build-qt-5-1-statically-on-windows/

to build it statically , but i can't find the qt creator ? everything is working great , like qt designer and everything.

What should I do ? it finished with no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt creator is a separate product, it's not in the Qt library package. Download it from: http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qtcreator/3.0/3.0.1/qt-creator-opensource-windows-x86-3.0.1.exe (or pick the one you want from: http://qt-project.org/downloads)

Comment: thanks but i already have one installed , but how do i link it with the statically built one ? i installed qt and qt creator came with it.